PHP - usort() With Partial Case Sensitivity
I have the following array items:
[{
    first_name: 'Rebecca'
}, {

    first_name: 'amy'
}, {
    first_name: 'Amy'
}, {

    first_name: 'stacy'
}]

I want the array to be sorted alphabetically according to the first_name property.  In a collision where the first_name properties are the same (ie. amy vs Amy), I want the value with the capital letter to come first.
In the above array, the sorted values should be:
[{
    first_name: 'Amy'
}, {

    first_name: 'amy'
}, {
    first_name: 'Rebecca'
}, {

    first_name: 'stacy'
}]

This is the current custom usort() I am using:
usort($users, function($a, $b){
    $first_name_compare = strcasecmp($a['first_name'], $b['first_name']);
    return $first_name_compare;
});

strcasecmp() is supposedly case-insensitive, but I've noticed it to be inconsistent.  In the above array example, strcasecmp() will sometimes return amy before Amy and vice versa.
What's a drop in for strcasecmp() in this use case?

You probably have to write your own comparison algorithm. Is that a problem?

Related Sort array by multiple values in PHP and php - sort list by multiple variables and How to properly write this usort function

Did you not find my more modern and concise answer to be helpful? @Lloyd

When strcasecmp() returns 0, you should fall back on strcmp().
usort($users, function($a, $b){
    $first_name_compare = strcasecmp($a['first_name'], $b['first_name']);
    if ($first_name_compare == 0) {
        $first_name_compare = strcmp($a['first_name'], $b['first_name']);
    }
    return $first_name_compare;
});


First compare case-insensitively, then to break ties compare case-sensitively.
?: is the Elvis operator -- if the value in the first evaluation is 0 (falsey), then fallback to the evaluation of the second comparison.
Code: (Demo)
usort(
    $users,
    fn($a, $b) => strcasecmp($a['first_name'], $b['first_name'])
        ?: strcmp($a['first_name'], $b['first_name'])
);
var_export($users);


Another viable approach is to isolate the column values as a flat array, sort case-insensitively, then sort casing-sensitively: (Demo)
$firstNames = array_column($users, 'first_name');
array_multisort($firstNames, SORT_STRING | SORT_FLAG_CASE, $firstNames, $users);
var_export($users);


Why SORT_NATURAL? That refers to how numeric substrings affect the sort order, and I wouldn't expect numbers in first names.

It doesn't matter which companion I give to SORT_FLAG_CASE in this scenario.  Fair shout anyhow, I've changed it to SORT_STRING.
